# Vertical Alignment - 2 fields same row

Tags: visualforce

I'm trying to align in to the same row, two input fields contained in the same block, is this possible or am I wasting my time trying to achieve this point.

I've been tried using `style= (margin, padding, position, etc...)...` any idea???

[image: This two highlighted fields must be in the same row aligned vertically at the same distance, between first and third row]

My Code:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Imperial System" columns="1" rendered="{!Customer_s_Price_List__c.System_Of_Measurement__c == 'Imperial System'
                                               && ( Customer_s_Price_List__c.Product_Type__c == 'Fabric' || Customer_s_Price_List__c.Product_Type__c == 'Tape') }">
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
        <apex:inputField value="{!Customer_s_Price_List__c.Wide_Imperial__c}"> 
           <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="Fabric_Tape_Imp" />
        </apex:inputField>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="Fabric_Tape_Imp" >
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="Full_Width" rendered="{!IF(Customer_s_Price_List__c.Wide_Imperial__c==TEXT(ProductMaxWidth),true,false)}"> 
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:inputField value="{!Customer_s_Price_List__c.Length_Units__c}" style="position:absolute; margin-top: -20pt; margin-left: -60pt; " 
                                            rendered="{!IF(Customer_s_Price_List__c.Wide_Imperial__c==TEXT(ProductMaxWidth),true,false)}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:inputtext value="{!Customer_s_Price_List__c.Long_Imperial__c}" style="margin-top: -9pt;" 
                                       rendered="{!IF(Customer_s_Price_List__c.Wide_Imperial__c==TEXT(ProductMaxWidth),true,false)}" 
                                       title="Please select units of long, and enter the value of length with no decimals" />
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Comment: This is definitel possible..you need to play around with apex:panelgrid and panelgroup components to make it work.

Comment: @Javier Your screenshot and the code is not matching. Can you please share the portion of the code which generates the output as shown in screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any other way to resolve this issue more that rerender the Visualforce page with an Apex Controller, even when all the time I was trying to avoid accomplish this, using more deep code, so solution below, and it's pretty easy, because is using selectOption method:

Now it's working smooth...

VF Page:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!Customer_s_Price_List__c.Length_Units__c}" size="1" style="margin-top: -8pt;" >
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!length_Units}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

Apex Controller:

```
public List<SelectOption> getlength_Units(){
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    options.add(new SelectOption('Yards','Yards'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('Feet','Feet'));
    return options;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of two fields in the same row sharing a label (if that is what you are looking for):

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.FirstName}"/>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel value="My Label"/>
                <apex:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.LastName}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Salutation}"/>
                </apex:panelGrid>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Birthdate}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.MailingCity}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

It is best not to fight with the platform's default CSS.

The output looks like this:

[image: screen shot]

If you want the fields one below the other then change `columns="2"` to `columns="1"`.

Comment: Sorry guys... I just realized that I made a mistake with my code... the right code is below, and the problem is still there... Thanks Saroj to catch the error...